# Have to use Both max-wdith and min-width instead of just width

Tags: html, css, razor-pages

I have an html table where I need the cells to be specific sizes. For some reason, the only way I can achieve this is by setting both max-width and min-width to the same value, instead of just width.

Each cell needs to be a different size, so I need to set it on each cell individually.

```css
.corrTable table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.corrTable td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}

.corrTable th {
  padding: 5px;
}

.corrTable>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  border: solid thin;
  /*background-color: #f9f9f9;*/
}
```

```html
<table class="corrTable" style="min-width:1615px">
  <tr>
    <td id="@i" style="max-width:75px;min-width:75px">@Model.log</td> <!--works-->
    <td id="@i" style="width:75px">@Model.log</td> <!-- does not work -->
    <td id="@i" width="75px">@Model.log</td> <!-- does not work-->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any idea?

Comment: `.corrTable table` should be `table.corrTable`. And you need `table-layout:fixed` for widths to work like you expect in tables.

Comment: Tried both the above changes, still didn't work

Comment: Hm. Can you show the HTML and CSS you now have, so I can take a look.

Comment: actuall your code show that the width is working

Comment: Also W3schools has some examples of table layouts: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp. For accessibility and easier navigation through tables I would also recommend using table headers and footers. https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/ 

The suggestion of Mr Lister should work to your needs 'table-layout:fixed'.